# Alter a nonunique index to a unique index

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a few non-unique constraints that I want to alter into unique constraints ( business rules have changed since the data model was made ).  Is there any way to do it with out dropping and recreating as a unique constraint?  I was thinking there would be an option in the `alter constraint` command, but I have not found anything.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify a constraint in the way you wish you can only drop and recreate it. If you want to do this with no downtime then look into the [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_redefi.htm) package.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot convert a non-unique index into a unique index.

(It's difficult to say what cannot be done.  I'm basing this answer on looking at the [ALTER INDEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_1010.htm#i2050158) page of the SQL Language Reference, searching for the word UNIQUE, and not finding any relevant hints.  I looked at 11g instead of 10g, but that's probably better in this case because there are a few features that exist in 10g but are only documented in 11g.)

However, you can use a non-unique index for a unique constraint.  But there are some [performance considerations](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/differences-between-unique-and-non-unique-indexes-part-i/): a unique index would be smaller and faster.

```
create table my_table(a number);

create index my_table_index on my_table(a);

alter table my_table add constraint my_table_unique unique (a)
    using index my_table_index;
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, just do drop and re-create the index:

```
DROP INDEX index_name;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name (col01,col02) TABLESPACE indx;
```