# Modify table index from unique to non unique

Tags: oracle

I wish to modify the index for a table from Unique to non unique.

The table is currently not empty. Do I have to clear all the rows before I do the update?

Comment: YOU CAN REFER THIS QUESTION
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917339/alter-a-nonunique-index-to-a-unique-index

Comment: You can't modify a constraint.in such a case drop and recreate it.

Comment: yes by modify-thats where I was going, do we need to drop and recreate an index on an empty table , i know we will need an empty table for non unique to unique, but is it the same other way around as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to clear all rows, you need only to drop the index and create it without the unique modifier:

```
create index my_non_unique_ix on my_table( my_col);
```

Comment: so unique to non-unique, table need not be empty. non-unique to unique, table needs to be empty, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Haran Murthy: also for non-unique to unique threre is no need for table to be empty. The only condition is that the the existing entries are unique.