# SQL Server: how to change a non-unique, non-clustered index to a unique, non-clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, unique-constraint

On Microsoft SQL Server, I have a non-clustered index, and I want to change it from non-unique to unique index.

Do I have to drop it and create a new one? Or is there a shortcut?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alter a nonunique index to a unique index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917339/alter-a-nonunique-index-to-a-unique-index)

Comment: Not really a dup to the one you ref, since it is oracle. However, you can't alter an index in TSQL. The TSQL Alter Index command does not support such things